# SceneKit applyForce in ARKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a node attached to the camera (`pointOfView` node) at position (0, 0, -0.3), it moves relative to the camera when panning the screen which is exactly what I want.

When I call `applyForce` on the physics body of the child node with `SCNVector3(0, 0, 5)` however it will only move outwards to the initial direction the camera facing, so once the device has been rotated applyForce will still send it in the direction the camera was initially facing, I want the ball to move forward in all cases. I added an illustration to help explain my point. Can anyone explain why this happens?

[image]

Thanks.